Publisher send the messages but subscribers cannot receive correctly in ROS
this is my publisher:
target_pub_ = nh_.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>("/move_base_simple/goal", 10);
...
void fsm::pubNewTarget(double next_target_[3])
{
    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped goal;
    goal.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    goal.header.frame_id = "world";

    goal.pose.position.x = next_target_[0];
    goal.pose.position.y = next_target_[1];
    goal.pose.position.z = next_target_[2];
    goal.pose.orientation.x = 0;
    goal.pose.orientation.y = 0;
    goal.pose.orientation.z = 0;
    goal.pose.orientation.w = 1;

    target_pub_.publish(goal);
    ROS_INFO("Published next target to /move_base_simple/goal: %f,%f,%f",goal.pose.position.x,goal.pose.position.y,goal.pose.position.z);

    cur_target_ = Eigen::Vector3d(next_target_[0], next_target_[1], next_target_[2]);
}

and this is my subscriber:
waypoint_sub_ = nh.subscribe("/move_base_simple/goal", 1, &EGOReplanFSM::waypointCallback, this);//(in a class)
...
void EGOReplanFSM::waypointCallback(const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedPtr &msg)
  {
    if (msg->pose.position.z < -0.1)
      return;

    cout << "Triggered!" << endl;
    // trigger_ = true;
    init_pt_ = odom_pos_;

    Eigen::Vector3d end_wp(msg->pose.position.x, msg->pose.position.y, msg->pose.position.z);
    ROS_INFO("target: %f,%f,%f",end_wp(0), end_wp(1), end_wp(2));

    planNextWaypoint(end_wp);
  }

There isn't other code about this subscriber and this publisher.
the result is like this:
[ INFO] [1718241065.242124381, 4061.818000000]: Published next target to /move_base_simple/goal: 1.800000,0.000000,1.600000
[ INFO] [1718241081.398708229, 4077.926000000]: Published next target to /move_base_simple/goal: 1.800000,1.600000,1.600000
[ INFO] [1718241147.840353409, 4138.438000000]: Published next target to /move_base_simple/goal: 1.800000,-1.600000,1.600000
[ INFO] [1718241065.242303178, 4061.818000000]: target: 1.800000,0.000000,1.600000
[ INFO] [1718241081.398879554, 4077.926000000]: target: 1.800000,1.600000,1.600000
[ INFO] [1718241091.883711821, 4088.330000000]: target: 642719.066674,4671808.218637,0.000000

How does it happen? Why the third message is wrong?
I tried rostopic echo /move_base_simple/goal this is the result:
WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published?
header: 
  seq: 1
  stamp: 
    secs: 3359
    nsecs: 182000000
  frame_id: "world"
pose: 
  position: 
    x: 1.8
    y: 1.6
    z: 1.6
  orientation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 1.0
---
header: 
  seq: 150
  stamp: 
    secs: 3368
    nsecs: 330504441
  frame_id: "map"
pose: 
  position: 
    x: 642719.0517464812
    y: 4671808.218661448
    z: 0.0
  orientation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 1.0
---
header: 
  seq: 151
  stamp: 
    secs: 3369
    nsecs: 478522309
  frame_id: "map"
pose: 
  position: 
    x: 642719.0680617385
    y: 4671808.256290132
    z: 0.0
  orientation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 1.0
---
header: 
  seq: 152
  stamp: 
    secs: 3370
    nsecs: 522523667
  frame_id: "map"
pose: 
  position: 
    x: 642719.0755269051
    y: 4671808.256290132
    z: 0.0
  orientation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 1.0


Why do you think the subscriber isn't receiving correctly? It looks correct to me. This is most likely an error with whatever is calling pubNewTarget.

Somehow the frame-id of rostopic echo /move_base_simple/goal shows the frames world an map.
Try rosinfo /move_base_simple/goal to find wich nodes are publishing to /move_Base_simple/goal.
